# Estimating $n^2$ after observing $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ and knowing $p$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, distribution-tails

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ be unknown and let $p\in (0,1]$ be known.

Suppose that we observe $X\sim Bin(n,p)$. This allows us to estimate $\widehat n= X/p$ and we can use the Chernoff inequality to bound the probability that it deviates significantly from $n$.

I'm interested in estimating the quantity $n^2$.

It's clear that using $(X/p)^2$ is not the right approach because

$$\mathbb E[(X/p)^2] = n/p + n(n-1) = n^2 + n(1/p-1).$$

To unbias the estimate, we can use
$$
\widehat {n^2} = (X/p)^2 - X/p\cdot(1/p-1).
$$

Question 1:

> **Is this the best unbiased estimator for $n^2$?**

Question 2:

> **How can we get tail bounds for the estimator?**

---

One easy tail bound would come from Chebyshev as bounding the variance seems easy.
Can we get sharper (Chernoff-style) bounds?

Since the only random variable here is $X\sim Bin(n,p)$, I guess that this is equivalent to looking for a sharp bound for $X^2$.

Comment: It seems rather perverse to estimate an unknown *perfect square* $(n^2)$ by a quantity that typically is not even an integer, let alone a perfect square! There are well-known examples that illustrate how "unbiasedness" can sometimes be an absurd criterion, and I think this may be of the same kind. (It might be interesting to consider the statistical properties of rounding your $\widehat{n^2}$ to the nearest perfect square.)

Comment: @r.e.s, there's a reason why I need the unbiasedness (I'm trying to estimate the square of the second norm of a frequency vector, where is entry is only observed after sampling). 
The unbiasedness allows the errors of the different coordinates to cancel each other instead of accumulate in the worst case.